# Celery can't connect to aws RDS and instead using 127.0.0.1

Tags: django, redis, celery, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django app running on Elastic beanstalk with celery and redis. 
The celery task that is failing is to process a photo and save some results in the database (which is a postgres RDS) and it's failing because it's trying to connect to the database on localhost:5432.

I have a debug task which doesn't interact with the database and I can see that it is received and executed.

My settings file has the following

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "localhost",
    "127.0.0.1",
    ".elasticbeanstalk.com",
]

if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'woodpecker',
            'USER': os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
            'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("DB_PASS"),
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost'
```

celery config file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings') # DON'T FORGET TO CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
# os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')

app = Celery('myapp')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
   print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I'm still having a problem running celery with supervisord so for now I do the following to start celery after logging to the ec2 instance

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
cd /opt/python/current/app/
celery worker -A myapp --loglevel=DEBUG
```

a snippet of the error I'm getting shows that celery is trying to connect to the database on localhost while it should connect to the postgres RDS from the settings file

```
[2019-07-28 17:58:27,486: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task photos.views.generate_features_async[6808ab5d-1160-456a-ae06-fbc2ec37e150] raised unexpected: OperationalError('could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Is your postgresql server installed on the same instance where celery is running ?

Comment: If you are using RDS then it is installed on different machune. If check your RDS instance you will get IP address where it is hosted and replace that in your settings

Comment: No, It's separated, though my ec2 has access to the database since my  app can use it to create user profiles and upload photo ... etc. so I don't also think it's a security/permissions issue

Comment: where should that ip go? since I already have database settings that are working alright

Comment: Can you check if RDS_DB_NAME environment variable is set before running celery worker command?

Comment: yeah it's there

Comment: Have you tried echo $RDS_DB_NAME after logging into EC2 instance ?

Comment: yes, i logged in, switched to my environment and then used this
`sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output YAML `

Comment: but now that you mention it, i tried to use python shell to print out environment variables and nothing for RDS is there!
do you know whats wrong there?

Comment: If you are running it manually from shell then you need to set the environment variable in currently running shell .

Comment: and yeah `echo $RDS_DB_NAME ` doesn't return it

Comment: thanks :) will try to do it, but don't know how since celery will get it's configs from settings.py

Comment: Not quite sure about it but you can trigger shell commands from eb_extensions config